# Remove active pseudo class after long touch

Tags: html, css, touch

I have been working on buttons for touch screen app.

Whenever user touches button for more than one second button stays active after lifting touch. I'd like to disable this functionality.

I have following CSS:

```
button {
    background: lightgray;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    user-select:none;
}

button:active {
    background: blue;
    color:white;
}
```

And html

```
<button>Click me </button>
```

I have fixed two issues already

- that such action doesn't trigger `onclick`, I have changed it to `onpointerup`
- context menu is being open (I disabled it globally)

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

Basically, what I need is for button to work with touch as if it was working with mouse. It would be best to have a solution in CSS, maybe in vanilla JS.

One side note: It shouldn't matter much but this project is in Blazor